# Angular 8 text input with dropdown

Tags: angular, search, input, dropdown

Trying to convert the list below to the input filed as dropdown , any help

**Component.html**

```html
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search report name here">         
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let report of reportList1 | ReportNameFilter : searchText">
            {{ report }}
        </li>   
    </ul>
</input>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
reportList1 = [
    'report one',
    'report two',
    'report three',
    'report four',
    'report five'
];
```

**pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'ReportNameFilter'
})
export class ReportNameFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
        if(!items) return [];
        if(!searchText) return items;
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        return items.filter(it => {
            return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        });
    }
}
```

Something like below:

[image]

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Comment: Can you give us an example of an implementation you tried?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Thank you so much, exactly what i'm looking for. my data is list of json Object. Can you please guide how to map an attribute of the object to text input

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template

Comment: Thank you... ng- tempate and formatter did the job.